# select checkbox in multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I have dropdowns. I select a checkbox by using javascript, but when I send the form, the option checked not taken into account

[image]

in this picture, despite the first option is checked but the number of option checked not updated, but when I check another option, the number updated as follow

[image]

this is my code:

[image]

and in my javascript:

```
  $("#contact").multiselect({
        show: ["bounce", 200],
        hide: ["explode", 1000],
        checkAllText: "Cocher tout",
        uncheckAllText: "Décocher tout",
        minWidth: 420,
        noneSelectedText: "Centre d'intérêt",
        selectedText: '# bus sélectionnés'
    });
var opti=$("#ui-multiselect-contact_option-0");
    opti.attr("checked", "checked");
    opti.attr("aria-selected", "true");
    opti.attr('disabled', "true");
```

Please help.

Comment: Try to make a fiddle that reproduce the issue please so we could help.